# Как удалить дубли с файл объёмом в 100ГБ?

Tags: linux, unix, текст, словари, awk

Есть txt файл объем которого 107ГБ свободно на винте 109 ГБ.
Что лучше использовать чтобы быстро избавиться от дублей строк в текстовом файле.

Пробовал команду    "awk '!seen[$0]++' text.txt"
Начинало все красиво и очень быстро но спустя 15-17 часов я уже видел как оно все по строчке делает и уж очень начал тупить комп.

Смотрю в сторону    uniq text.txt> text_new.txt
но не знаю на сколько оно будет лучше предыдущей команды.

Кто что сможет посоветовать ?

Comment: `uniq` требует, чтобы строки были отсортированы, если это не так, то их надо отсортировать через `sort`, а значит можно сразу указать флаг `-u` и останутся одни уникальные строки и без использования `uniq`

Comment: @BOPOH Файл не отсортирован. Как я понял мне нужно выполнить вод такую команду 

cat text.txt | sort | uniq > new_text.txt ?

Comment: Использование cat очень сильно скажется на производительности. Sort прекрасно умеет читать файл

Comment: @KoVadim если не трудно напишите команду которую мне использовать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: sort file.txt -u > result.txt

Answer (score 1):

uniq не отработает, если строки не будут отсортированы. То есть, все пойдет насмарку. Есть разные варианты, но все сильно зависит от количества тех самых дублей. Если дубликатов не много и они могут вместиться в 2 гига, то можно сделать так. С помощью grep отбираются только те строки, которые начинаются на 'aa' (или aaa), Этих строк будет не много и если среди них есть дубликаты, то они будут все здесь. Постепенно, проходя по файлу, можно выбрать все группы. Код будет где то такой (пишу на перле, раз есть awk и linux, значит есть перл).

```
for (my $l = 'aaa'; $l ne 'qqq'; $l++) {
  `egrep '^$l' file.txt | sort -u >> res.txt`
}
```

Если места будет не хватать, то можно переносить файл с результатом на другой комп. Понятно, что указанный способ хорош для английского текста, а вот для кириллицы нужно шлифовать.

Также, можно ручками задавать диапазон и потихоньку продвигаться.

**Вариант два.** Для этого нужен будет mysql или что то подобное. Делаем там таблицу, с одним столбцом и делаем значения в этом поле уникальными. Дальше, построчно (но лучше пачками) заливаем строки. Теперь это уже проблема базы отслеживать дубликаты. Так как базу можно разместить на другой машине, проблема с доступным местом решается:)

**Вариант три.** Так как это линукс, то можно примонтировать файловую систему с другой машины, где есть достаточно свободного места.

**Вариант четыре.** Если ОЗУ достаточно, то можно рискнуть запустить прям сразу sort -u. Я буквально недавно сортировал файл размером около 800 мегабайт (да, это в 120 раз меньше, но все же) и он управился за минуту (на машине с i3, 8Gb ОЗУ) И думаю, что больше всего времени было потрачено на чтение/запись файла (да, там не ssd, а обычный диск).

**Вариант пять.** Тут уже нужно смотреть, а что за данные внутри. Если там, к примеру, ip адреса, то можно просто завести в памяти битовый массив (а это будет 2 ^^ 32 / 8 = 512 мб!) и просто за линейное время проставить биты. Потом точно также ещё раз пройтись по результирующему массиву и восстановить адреса.

**Вариант шесть.** Если текст в каждой строке разный, тогда можно придумать хэш функцию, которая будет кодировать в каждую строку в байт (даже подойдет обычная сумма, но нужно экспериментировать). Для одинаковый строк функция будет давать одинаковый хэш код. Но не наоборот (то есть, могут быть строки, которые имеют одинаковый код, но значения различны - называется коллизия). Теперь, пробегая по файлу, считаем для каждой строки хэш. Если он равен заданому, выписываем строку в отдельный файл. При правильном подходе, файл будет разделен на 200-256 кусков, то есть, по пол гига каждый. А эти куски можно уже и sort -u прогнать. В принципе, это очень похоже на первый способ, там просто хэш функция была простой - первые два-три символа строки.

**UPD**

Вначале не заметил, что там свободно 109 Гигов. Это сильно меняет все. Я вначале подумал, что всего 109 гигов и поэтому свободно только 2:)

Comment: А uniq  нормально дружит с кириллицей ?

Comment: @4BAL0V, ни для программы `sort`, ни для `uniq`, интерпретация содержимого никакой роли не играет: сравниваются байты. пример: `echo -e '\x00\n\x00\n\x01' | sort -u | wc -l` возвращает, как и ожидается, `2` (две уникальные строки).

Answer (score 0):

Если порядок строк не важен, то можно реализовать сортиролвку слиянием, которая  может работать с данными на диске.